# How to get text from <a> tag which has href starts with "#"?

Tags: javascript, html

When I use the following script to get the link, the href starting with "#" will automatically add a prefix. How to avoid it?

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event)
{
    let elem = event.target;
    let jsonObject =
    {
        Key: 'mousemove',
        Value: elem.href
    };
    window.chrome.webview.postMessage(jsonObject);
});
```

Also, how to handle the case where "#" is in the middle of the text.

```html
<p>Test:</p>

<ul>
  <li><a href="https://example.com">Website</a></li>
  <li><a href="mailto:test@example.com">Email</a></li>
  <li><a href="tel:+123456789">Phone</a></li>
  <li><a href="#ted.test@micr#osoft.com">Test #</a></li>
  <li><a href="Test#Test">Test # 2</a></li>
</ul>
```